# How to set proxyPort and proxyHost within a pom

Tags: maven, proxy

I have a JBehave suite which calls a 3rd party service. Currently I need to append -Dhttp.proxyPort=myport and -Dhttp.proxyHost=myhost when running the install phase on the command line.

Is there a way of setting those properties within the pom so I can remove them from the command?

I've tried adding them within the  tag at the top. And I've also tried the surefire plugin like below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <http.proxyPort>myPort1</http.proxyPort>
            <http.proxyHost>myHost1</http.proxyHost>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `<argLine>` config element instead of `<systemPropertyVariables>` as described at the bottom of [this example page from the Surefire plugin docs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).

```
<configuration>
    <argLine>-Dhttp.proxyPort=myport -Dhttp.proxyHost=myhost</argLine>
</configuration>
```